# Ionic Push Bad Request 400

Tags: python, post, curl, push-notification, ionic-framework

EDIT:

**So it looks like the problem is that the output I am seeing has everything in single quotes, instead of double quotes, and also there are a "u" character being thrown in. Does anyone have an idea of what could be causing this? If I try to validate the JSON by changing everything to double quotes as well as removing the "u" then it validates properly.**

**EDIT: 2
Turns out that the problem was using urlencode, as soon as I changed to using json.dumps() everything has worked perfectly fine.**

I am working on implementing Ionic Push into my Ionic app and am having trouble creating a properly formatted request for the "Push" service that you need to hit to actually send the push notifications.

I am doing a python implementation and following the way that they are saying to set it up in their [documentation](http://docs.ionic.io/v1.0/docs/push-sending-push).

So in the code below you can see that I am logging out the `Logger.info(post_data)`, if I take exactly what is logged out from there and do a manual curl request I am able to receive the push notifications to the device correctly.

But as soon as I try to send a `POST` request to the service to send the message I receive back a `400 BAD REQUEST` response so it leads me to believe that I must be missing something in my headers/authentication? My implementation using `urllib2` seems to match what is shown in the setup but I am still seeing a problem. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

This is the logged output from `Logger.info(post_data)` and you will also find the code below:

```
# Output
{'notification': {'alert': u"Automatic Investments is disabled! We aren't buying you Bitcoin!"}, 'tokens': [u'APA91bGyHR56ANGhiDvlgY7DM7fda2EG4Hp8hSw2arJmaib-BXHT8YWLw5xMloUgZSQvOdzD3Qpg6FMTZeS8b9c2Tl0Rd86qbDa2h_HJKY-pOMP95uNdbUSjJJMuvd-TOs-rhh8gaj6Hs9G0q2LsG7Bc0HtII-O3cQ']}


# Code
class PushService(object):

    def __init__(self, app=None):
        self.app = app
        if app is not None:
            self.init_app(app)

    def init_app(self, app):
        self.url = app.config['IONIC_PUSH_ENDPOINT']
        self.app_id = app.config['IONIC_PUSH_APP_ID']
        self.api_key = app.config['IONIC_PUSH_API_KEY']
        self.secret_api_key = app.config['IONIC_PUSH_PRIVATE_KEY']

        Logger.info('URL: ' + str(self.url))
        Logger.info('APP_ID: ' + str(self.app_id))
        Logger.info('API_KEY: ' + str(self.api_key))
        Logger.info('SECRET_KEY: ' + str(self.secret_api_key))

    def send(self, user, device, message):

        Logger.info('DEVICE_ID: ' + device.device_id)

        tokens = [device.device_id]

        # Set up the data of POST for the push
        post_data = {"tokens": tokens,
                     "notification": {
                         "alert": message
                         }
                     }

        # Encode for passing to urllib
        data = urllib.urlencode(post_data)

        Logger.info(post_data)

        Logger.info('RIGHT BEFORE ATTEMPTING TO SEND')

         app_id = self.app_id
         app_key = self.secret_api_key
         url = self.url
         req = urllib2.Request(url, data=data)
         req.add_header("Content-Type", "application/json")
         req.add_header("X-Ionic-Application-Id", app_id)
         b64 = base64.encodestring('%s:%s' % (app_key, '')).replace('\n', '')
         req.add_header("Authorization", "Basic %s" % b64)
         resp = urllib2.urlopen(req)

         print resp
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone else is having the same problem, make sure that you don't use urllib.urlencode(post_data), use json.dumps(post_data) instead and the above code will work.